# WH40K: Deathwatch: What helmet is this?

Tags: warhammer-40k, armor

The cover of the Warhammer 40K: Deathwatch RPG's core rulebook depicts several space marines. One of them (second from the left in the picture below) is wearing an unusual snouted helmet design.

At first I thought it might be a [Mk. IV-pattern helmet](https://www.games-workshop.com/resources/catalog/product/600x620/99120101143_MarkIVSpaceMarines03.jpg), but that doesn't seem right as the vents are not aligned the same way.

It also seems to have "ears" moulded into it. Given this, as well as the pelt on the marine's shoulders, it seems like the marine may be a Space Wolf. Could this be some sort of artificer-made armour mark?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions as to what this armour/helmet design may be.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've got it. After looking into the Space Wolves a bit, it seems they're fond of wearing wolf-themed artificer helms.

[image]

Looking at the ridges and holes (whiskers?) on the muzzle, the eyes, and the swept back "ears", this seems to be the helmet style. The pelt on the shoulders suggests he's of the Space Wolves, which would fit this style.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a [Mark IV Maximus](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/File:WBMk4.jpg) combined with [Mark VI Corvus](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/File:CorvusMini.jpg). The "ears" mold could be the vents of the Corvus pattern drawn a bit back and the beak that is serrated with the Maximus vents.

By the look of the right shoulder pad, he isn't a Space Wolf, the art isn't showing the bright yellow, it shows a faded bronze, closest to that color are the [Blood Wolves](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Blood_Wolves), a successor of the [Space Wolves](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Space_Wolves), but I don't think the Deathwatch recruits 'em heretics.

By the looks of it, it is the "signature" of the artist as an added bonus, could be wrong for all I know, but that is my theory.

Comment: It looks a bit like both of those helmets, but not enough like either to call it a match. As for the pauldron, it may just be the artist's technique of shading, taking the lighting and fog into account.